# MongoDB: Bulk changing all field types in python

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a ton of documents (around 10 million) and I need to change their field type. The usual forEach function (just looping through every value) seems to take forever and is clearly not viable in the timeframe I have (it basically took all night for one out of four updates)

I've heard that bulkwrites may be able to do it but I'm getting mixed messages. I saw a confusing  answer on this site, for example, says that there's no written function to do it (you would have to do some workaround), others say that it can be done with updates in Python, using pymongo.

I was wondering if there was a quicker way to mass changes of field type (string->double, string -> int) using python? I can also work from the console but I find even less solutions there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using aggregation query in the mongo shell

Something like

```
db.your_collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      field1: {
        $convert: {
          input: "$field1",
          to: "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $out: "your_collection" }
])
```

More info here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/